Racket custom 'infix' operator
I am still learning this. So my question title and this code both may be incorrect.
I am trying to define a new operator for appending. The inspiration for this is some OCaml code I am porting to Racket.
Compiles and executes but the test doesn't complete.
Test
(: fn1 ( Integer Integer -> Integer))
(define (fn1 x y)
  (displayln x)
  (+ x y)
 )

;; Test linspcm
( check-equal? (linspcm  '(0) (@) 1 2 fn1) '(1 2 3 4) "Test unsuccessfull")

Code
(define-syntax-rule (@) (append))

(define-syntax-rule  (linspcm z (@) x n f)
  (match n
    [0 z]
    [1 (f x)]
    [_ (let* ([m (/ n 2)])
         (displayln n)
         ((linspcm z (@) x m f) (@)
         (linspcm z (@) (+ x m) (- n m) f))
      )
    ]
  )
)

Is this feasible ?
Update : DrRacket runs out of memory.Earlier I used emacs.Macro expander does not end.

Racket doesn't have operators. Everything is a function. If you really want infix instead of prefix, a value between two .'s in a list is moved to the front; (1 . + . 2) becomes (+ 1 2) for example.

The test code stalls at this time. It compiles though. Is it supposed to show an error ? The only error caused is : linspcm: use does not match pattern: (linspcm z (@) x n f)   in: linspcm  if I make a mistake in that pattern. So even ((linspcm z  (@)  x m f) . (@) .          (linspcm z (@) (+ x m) (- n m) f))
does not show any error but it may not make sense ?  Is it infinite ?

The body of the macro has recursive calls that look like they never stop expanding. Why are you using a macro at all instead of a normal function?

I realised it is a function. Initially I was experimenting.

I realised after posting my question that the syntax-rule I needed is minimal. I also learnt based on the comments that the infix between two dots (. (@) .) becomes a prefix . The code that compiles and executes is
(define-syntax-rule (@) append)

(: linspcm : ((Listof Integer) Integer Integer
              (Integer ->  Integer) -> (Listof Integer)))
(define  (linspcm z  x n f)

  (match n
    [0 z]
    [1 (list (f x))]
    [_ (let* ([m (quotient n 2)])
         (displayln n)
         ((linspcm z    x m f) . (@) .
         (linspcm z  (+ x m) (- n m) f))
      )
    ]
  )
)

Note : This is my code experiment.
